What is the most efficient way in Pandas to search for dates entries in a dataframe before or after a given date?
I am trying to determine whether a given set of obstetrics patients have recieved their flu shots in the current flu season.
That is, I have essentially three dataframes:
>>> edds
    name expected_delivery_date
0  Susan             2024-12-01
1  Susan             2023-10-01
2  Marie             2024-10-15

>>> flu_shots
    name flu_shot_date
0  Susan    2023-09-01
1  Marie    2022-09-01


>>> flu_season_begin_dates
0       2024-09-01
1       2023-09-01
2       2022-09-01
3       2021-09-01

What is the most efficient way to identify which women got a flu shot (a) before their due date but (b) on or after the start of the most recent flu season?
>>> got_flu_shot
   name   expected_delivery_date   got_required_flu_shot
0 Susan  2024-12-01                False
1 Susan  2023-10-01                True
2 Marie  2023-10-01                True


I can think of going row-by-row by (name, expected_delivery_date) and searching for the "most recent flu shot before the delivery" and "most recent flu season start date" but that feels inherently inefficient.

Are the two Susans in the edds dataframe the same patient? Is it assumed that each patient only has one flu shot date?

Can we assume only one injection per year? (I've understood the question now, sorry)

No, I tried building this out, and I was right. The example is entirely inconsistent. Marie only got one shot in 2022, but then appears as true for the 2023 season, yet there's only one expected_delivery_date in 2024 so no matter how you look at it, she missed a year (or, RIP Marie and someone needs to inform the clinic). This is unworkable as a [mcve]

Assuming a slightly different example for edds and flu_shots and that there is only one season per year:
    name expected_delivery_date
0  Susan             2024-12-01
1  Susan             2023-10-01
2  Marie             2024-10-15
3  Marie             2022-10-15
4  Helen             2022-11-15

    name flu_shot_date
0  Susan    2023-09-01
1  Marie    2022-09-01
2  Helen    2022-05-01

This can be solved by using two merge_asof and a check that the most recent flu_shot_date is between the season_start (with a limit of 1 year) and the expected_delivery_date:
# ensure all dates are datetime
edds['expected_delivery_date'] = pd.to_datetime(edds['expected_delivery_date'])
flu_shots['flu_shot_date'] = pd.to_datetime(flu_shots['flu_shot_date'])
flu_season_begin_dates = pd.to_datetime(flu_season_begin_dates)

# merge
out = (
    pd.merge_asof(
        pd.merge_asof(
            edds.reset_index().sort_values(by='expected_delivery_date'),
            flu_shots.sort_values(by='flu_shot_date'),
            left_on='expected_delivery_date',
            right_on='flu_shot_date',
            by='name',
            tolerance=pd.Timedelta(days=365),
        ),
        flu_season_begin_dates.sort_values().rename('season_start'),
        left_on='expected_delivery_date',
        right_on='season_start',
        tolerance=pd.Timedelta(days=365),
    )
    .set_index('index')
    .reindex(edds.index)
    .assign(
        got_required_flu_shot=lambda x: x['flu_shot_date'].ge(
            x['season_start']
        )
    )
)

Output:
    name expected_delivery_date flu_shot_date season_start  got_required_flu_shot
0  Susan             2024-12-01           NaT   2024-09-01                  False
1  Susan             2023-10-01    2023-09-01   2023-09-01                   True
2  Marie             2024-10-15           NaT   2024-09-01                  False
3  Marie             2022-10-15    2022-09-01   2022-09-01                   True
4  Helen             2022-11-15    2022-05-01   2022-09-01                  False

